# C# best practice with using multiple similar methods with different properties?

Tags: c#, dry

I'm trying to simplify and reduce my code.

I have a method like this:

```
private bool FindMatchingValue(string value, string response, string dataType) {
  bool isFound = false;
  switch (dataType) {
    case "Date":
      var parsedDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(response).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
      isFound = checkEquality(value, parsedDate);
      break;
    case "Time":
      var parsedTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(response).ToString("HH:mm:00.000");
      isFound = checkEquality(value, parsedTime);
      break;
  }
  return isFound;
}
```

I have another method which takes a list of strings like this:

```
private bool FindMatchingValue(List<string> values, string response, string dataType) {
  bool isFound = false;
  switch (dataType) {
    case "Date":
      var parsedDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(response).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
      isFound = checkEquality(values, parsedDate);
      break;
    case "Time":
      var parsedTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(response).ToString("HH:mm:00.000");
      isFound = checkEquality(values, parsedTime);
      break;
  }
  return isFound;
}
```

The only real difference with these methods is that one property.
Is there a better approach I can use, so I don't have to repeat the repeating switch case code?

Comment: The body of both methods are the same so I guess you just copy-pasted that part, but if the body is actually the same (alike) you could just pass the first method into a new list of values and use the second method - however (since I don't know your codebase) you could potentially run into a world of hurt : it always depends

Comment: Is `checkEquality` overloaded to take either a list of values or a single value?

Comment: the difference is actually value (type string) vs values (type List<string>)

Comment: Yes - checkEquality is overloaded to use string or List<string>

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it better fits codereview.stackexchange. It could have an infinite number of valid refactoring answers so I don't think it fits SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already have a version that handles multiple values. Handling a single value is a special case of that so

```
private bool FindMatchingValue(string value, string response, string dataType) {
  bool isFound = false;
  switch (dataType) {
    case "Date":
      var parsedDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(response).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
      isFound = checkEquality(value, parsedDate);
      break;
    case "Time":
      var parsedTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(response).ToString("HH:mm:00.000");
      isFound = checkEquality(value, parsedTime);
      break;
  }
  return isFound;
}
```

Could just be

```
private bool FindMatchingValue(string value, string response, string dataType) {
    return FindMatchingValue(new List{ value }, response, dataType);
}
```

This way you don't need to duplicate the code, just provide an alternate method signature that can be called depending upon what is easier at the time. It's fairly common (in my experience) to see overloads like this all refer to a single method that has the necessary business logic.

Equally the List version could be replaced with a call to the original version of the single value

```
private bool FindMatchingValue(List<string> values, string response, string dataType) {
    return values.Any(value => FindMatchingValue, response, dataType);
}
```

But the choice is yours.

Answer (score 1):

Use the list-version and flip the arguments around, and make it a params. It will now works for both.

```
private bool FindMatchingValue(string response, string dataType, params string[] values) {
  bool isFound = false;
  switch (dataType) {
    case "Date":
      var parsedDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(response).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
      isFound = checkEquality(values, parsedDate);
      break;
    case "Time":
      var parsedTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(response).ToString("HH:mm:00.000");
      isFound = checkEquality(values, parsedTime);
      break;
  }
  return isFound;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first method that only has the one string, you could do this:

```
private bool FindMatchingValue(string value, string response, string dataType) => return FindMatchingValue(new List<String>{ value }, response, dataType)
```

It's a single line function that just calls the other